# Snapshot notification

Tags: wallet, snapshot

> When the IOTA foundation performs a network-wide snapshot, they define a milestone index (i.e. the index of a transaction issued by the Coordinator). Nodes who have not seen that milestone (because they are not synced) will not be able to verify the snapshot. All other nodes that have this milestone can verify it, since it confirms the same transactions for everybody.

Users are notified about snapshot via discord or GitHub about snapshot time.

Is there an automatic way to notify users via wallets that snapshot is going to occur on this date.

Answer (score 1):

The new Trinity Wallet will be statefull, meaning that it is going to store your balance information and history locally so, when a snapshot occurs you will just not notice it because the relation between your identity (seed) in the Tangle and your addresses will be reconstructed automatically using the data stored on your computer.

To address your question: there is not yet. We will have to wait to see if Trinity notify us of snapshots. Eventually the IOTA network will switch to regional snapshots and stop doing this globaly.